# Detecting User Choice with VBA Outmail application in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect whether or not the user clicks "Send" in the Outlook application that is displayed. I've tried reading the value of .Display similarly to how one would detect user input when using the FileDialog application (someInt = .Show), to no avail. I can't find any documentation on the Outmail Application, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Outmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With Outmail
    .To = clientEmail
    .CC = projectManagerEmail
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = projectName & " (PO # " & poNumber & ", Job #" & projectNumber & ") - " & fileType & " (" & fileName & ")"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileType & "\" & folderName & "\" & fileName & ".pdf"
    .Display
    .Save 
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to intercept the <kbd>Send</kbd> operation in Outlook.

In Outlook, go to VBA Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>), then paste below into the **ThisOutlookSession** under **Microsoft Outlook Objects**.

Make sure your operations works in Outlook, then close Outlook. You may have to Sign the code, change Macro Security Settings depending on your environment. Value of **Cancel** is what determines if the user has clicked Send (e.g. clicked -> Cancel=False).

Since there is no direct way to get the value of Cancel, may be you have to create a unique text file in local temp folder and pick it up in Excel to indicate it is Sent.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal oItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Add Operations or Sub calls here
    MyCheck01 oItem, bCancel
End Sub

Private Sub MyCheck01(ByVal oItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Do operations here. If Send is to be aborted, set Cancel to True.
End Sub
```

You will also need to define this **olMailItem** in Excel (`Const olMailItem = 0`).

Comment: Thanks for the input! After some more searching, I was able to find a forum thread that was able to help me out (link below). I'm sure your solution would also have worked, so I'm going to mark it as the answer anyway. Thanks again!
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/692890-evaluating-if-outlook-email-displayed-excel-visual-basic-applications-sent-closed.html